# Размер текста в listview

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

В списке изменяю размер текста по нажатию кнопки, а он изменяет только верхнюю строку, а надо во всем списке.
Activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Big">

</Button>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActiviy:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textView1;
    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get reference of widgets from XML layout
        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        // Initializing a new String Array
        String[] fruits = new String[] {
            "Ambarella",
            "African mango",
            "American Black Elderberry",
            "Ackee",
            "American persimmon",
            "Babaco"
        };
        // Create a List from String Array elements
        List < String > fruits_list = new ArrayList < String >
            (Arrays.asList(fruits));
        // Create an ArrayAdapter from List
        ArrayAdapter < String > arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < String >
            (this, R.layout.list, fruits_list) {
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    // Get the Item from ListView
                    final View view = super.getView(position, convertView,
                        parent);
                    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
                    OnClickListener btnbig = new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            textView1.setTextSize(40);
                        }
                    };
                    btn.setOnClickListener(btnbig);
                    return view;
                }
            };
        // DataBind ListView with items from ArrayAdapter
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

файл list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:padding="10dp">
</TextView>`
```